# Store Very Large Arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

So I am working on a problem at HackerEarth which requires me to store an integer array of size 10^9.
I am trying to store the array using vector but I get runtime error SIGABRT when I try to Submit my Solution.
Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned int h, c, q;
    cin >> h >> c >> q;
    vector<unsigned int> minht(h + 1);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= h; i++)
        minht[i] = 0;
    unsigned int hc, st, et;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
    {
        cin >> hc >> st >> et;
        for (unsigned int j = 1; j <= h; j++)
        {
            if (j >= st && j <= et)
            {
                if (hc > minht[j])
                    minht[j] = hc;
            }
        }
    }
    unsigned int hq, tq;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= q; i++)
    {
        cin >> hq >> tq;
        if (hq > minht[tq])
            cout << "YES" << endl;
        else
            cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
}
```

The code works fine when value of `h` is not very large(10^9) but I get SIGABRT when value of `h` is very large.

Any Suggestions?

EDIT:
So I tried rewriting my entire code and my new code looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned int h,c,q,mh=0;
    cin>>h>>c>>q;
    vector<unsigned int> hc(c+1);
    vector<unsigned int> st(c+1);
    vector<unsigned int> et(c+1);
    for(unsigned int i=1;i<=c;i++)
    {
        cin>>hc[i]>>st[i]>>et[i];
        if(mh<hc[i])mh=hc[i];
    }
    unsigned int ht,ti;
    for(unsigned int i=1;i<=q;i++)
    {
        int flag=0;int ct=0;
        cin>>ht>>ti;
        if(ht<=mh)
        {
            for(unsigned int j=1;j<=c;j++)
            {
                if(ti>=st[j] && ti<=et[j])
                {
                    if(ht<=hc[j])
                    {
                        ct=1;break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(ct==0)cout<<"YES\n";
        else cout<<"NO\n";

    }

}
```

and the solution was now accepted.
What I did was redesign the algorithm so that instead of having to store 1 VERY LARGE array of 4 GB, I had to store 3 LARGE arrays, each of maximum 40 MB.

So the problem is now solved but I but I still don't think that problem was related to memory issues.

Because when I tried to create a `int` vector of size `10E8`, just to test out the online compiler, I got a specific `Memory Limit Exceeded` Error. But when I changed the size to `10E9` I got `SIGABRT` again. So although the memory issue is there, `SIGABRT` is being caused by declaring an array of `10E9` size.

Any idea what could be causing this??

Also, I first created the program on my own compiler and then submitted it online. I can't debug the program on my setup since the program requires me to enter `10E7` data values before I encounter the error, so I thought that it would be easier to do it on HackerEarth.

Comment: Integer overflow.

Comment: Don't these sites allow you to debug your code?  There are so many of these "hacker" or "online judge" questions, where the answer takes minimal debugging effort.

Comment: 8bytes * 10^9 -> 8GB data. Maybe you are at end of your ram?

Comment: Most likely the whole point of the task is to design a solution that does not require to use that much memory.

Comment: What is h, c, and q inputs in your program for? What is the expected output?

Comment: I suggest you take that question, get a *real* compiler (not an online one), write the solution you feel is correct, *debug the code on your own compiler if necessary*.  Once you have that, **then** you "submit your answer", and stop the trial and error online stuff that so many seem to be doing.  You are risking a downvote due to a lack of debugging effort.

Comment: Does it have to be `unsigned int`? If the numbers are small and you can get away with `int8_t`, it would reduce your memory requirement to 1 GB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a large array of numbers (10^9 size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358387/creating-a-large-array-of-numbers-109-size)

Comment: link to the problem?

Comment: @CinCout here: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/queues/basics-of-queues/practice-problems/algorithm/weird-planet-2000a170/

Comment: @mayankbudhwani *Because when I tried to create a int vector of size 10E8, just to test out the online compiler, I got a specific Memory Limit Exceeded* -- Sounds like the artificial limit that is placed by the online judge.  That does not sound like an error emitted by the C++ library.  *But when I changed the size to 10E9 I got SIGABRT again* -- That looks like a legitimate runtime memory limit, however that sounds as if you're running a 32-bit application, and not 64-bit (1 Gb memory is certainly doable if the program is 64-bits).